# Lodash orderBy Function Not Sorting Correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Hi Everyone having an issue with a lodash function with react. I am trying to order an array of strings. I am copying the code exactly from the documentation which i used in the playground there and works fine but when i try run it in my code i have the same issue which i had while using the sort array.

Grabbing my array and throwing it right into the orderBy function but it is not order it correctly.

I want the editionsCount to sort according to its value but it keeps ordering the numbers not based on their actual value.

For example 108 will be smaller than 23 because 2 is bigger than three.

Here is the code I am running the lodash function in

```
const stableSort = (array, comparator) => {
    console.log(_.orderBy(array, ["editionsCount"], ["desc"]));
  }
```

Here is a screenshot of my response

[image]

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This is the exactly how strings are compared, lexicographically. If you want to compare them as if they were numbers you need to convert them using to number

Comment: Can I do so in the orderBy function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `editionsCount` is a string, and is sorted by lexical order.

The `_.orderBy()` function also accepts a function as the iteratee. To order by numeric order, supply a function that converts a string to a number. I've used the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) operator.

```js
const arr = [{"editionsCount":"1"},{"editionsCount":"2"},{"editionsCount":"10"},{"editionsCount":"20"}]

// sort by numeric order
const sortByNumericValue = _.orderBy(arr, o => +o.editionsCount, ["desc"])
console.log(sortByNumericValue)

// Sort by lexical order
const sortByLexicalOrder = _.orderBy(arr, o => o.editionsCount, ["desc"])
console.log(sortByLexicalOrder)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```